# How can I get maximum performance of WebBrowser control without renaming the executable to iexplore.exe?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, native

I'm writing a native application that that does a lot of CSS3 animations in an embedded [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but the animations are much more fluid in the standalone IE10. I've read [an article](http://zett42.de/software/2013/04/04/performance-issue-of-embedded-ie-browser-control-and-how-to-fix-it/) that deals with the same problem, and I've tried everything suggested in the article, including:

- Setting [feature controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION, FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING
- Replacing `::PeekMessage(pMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE)` with `::GetQueueStatus(QS_ALLEVENTS)` in the message loop

Yet, the performance is still worse compared to IE10 - and that's also the conclusion of the article.

So I renamed my executable to `iexplore.exe` and guess what? It's now **as fast and as fluid** as the standalone browser.

I guess there is some kind of code in the WebBrowser control that does this: `if (ProcessName() == "iexplore.exe") { EnableMagic(); }`

But seriously, there should be a way to get the same performance without pretending to be IE. Any ideas?

Comment: :) The whole thing with the registry entries that control browser features is bizarre. For example, you have to add your executable name under `Internet Explorer/Main/FeatureControl/FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING` to enable GPU rendering. Why not simply provide an API for this?

Comment: By renaming to `iexplore.exe` a lot of things happen - likely due to a carefully optimized, default configuration: for example, Image File Execution Options (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\iexplore.exe`).
I suggest comparing start-up of the "good" setup (application renamed to `iexplore.exe`) vs the "bad" one (original application) using a profiler such as [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (simpler to use) or [API Monitor v2](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) (a lot more details).

Comment: Hi Danko, I realize this is a very old question, but I was wondering if you came across any new information on the magic that iexplore.exe does in the meantime. Or if there are any other magic names than iexplore.exe, that I could rename my executable to?