# Why is Windows.Forms.WebBrowser slower than iexplore.exe?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I observed that web pages using a lot of JavaScript -- in my case FluentUI controls -- are performing well using `iexplore.exe` but when I open the same HTML page using a `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` component. Performance is much worse.

How can I make `WebBrowser` as fast as IE?

Steps to reproduce:

- Open my [test file](http://playground1337.net/dropdown.html) using IE11

  - Open dropdown
  - Dropdown list should appear in a approximately 1 second
  - Scroll up and down and see immediate reaction
- Now open URL `http://playground1337.net/dropdown.html` in a `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`. You can e.g. use [this sample WebBrowser program](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1072026/Csharp-Web-Browser) or [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/13598/extended-net-2-0-webbrowser-control)

  - Open dropdown
  - It takes about 2-3 seconds until dropdown list appears
  - Scroll up and down and see how sluggish it feels

This question sounds a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051072/ie-11-webgl-performance-slow-when-using-webbrowser-control) but the answer is not applicable/needed here. My sample file uses [`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#understanding-legacy-document-modes) to make the `WebBrowser` component use the latest rendering engine. The mentioned answer uses [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser-emulation) which has no positive effect when using `x-ua-compatible`.

By visiting [`https://html5test.com/`](https://html5test.com/) you'll see that both IE11 and `WebBrowser` get 312 points. So it seems that indeed both are using the same rendering engine. But IE is still faster. Why?

Ideas I had but which I could not confirm:

- IE is creating a subprocess using parameter `prefetch:2`. Is this some kind of optimization?
  [image]
- When scrolling up and down using IE, GPU usage raises by about 10%:
  [image]
  When using the above mentioned `WebBrowser` programs, GPU usage is very high (70-80%).
  [image]
  Is `WebBrowser` doing some extra work? Is IE doing some optimizations?
- Maybe I can directly embed IE into my application using [command line parameter `-embedding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85))? Unfortunately when using that parameter there is no visible window.

Comment: I reproduced the issue in WebBrowser. I think that's because WebBrowser uses lower IE 11 version than the IE 11 in your computer. I tried the webpage in IE 11 on win10 and it's fast. I also tried the webpage in IE 11 on win7 and the performance is the same with it in WebBrowser. If I visit https://html5test.com/ in WebBrowser, I find that it shows *You're using IE 11 on Windows 8*. So I think WebBrowser uses lower IE 11 version than IE 11 on win10 which causes the performance slower. Maybe you can use  another webbrowser like [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for testing -- so it is not just me. Actually the set `x-ua-compatible` tag should make `WebBrowser` use the latest IE version. But that works only partly and that is the whole problem here.

Comment: I just realized that this question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107601/how-can-i-get-maximum-performance-of-webbrowser-control-without-renaming-the-exe. A possible "solution" is renaming the executable containing the ``WebBrowser`` component to `iexplore.exe`.

Comment: I tried the solution and it works. So amazing... I think you can also put the solution into an answer so that other community members in future in similar kind of issues can find the workaround quickly. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I tested all registry settings concerning `iexplore.exe`. No luck. Debugging revealed that `_wcsicmp("myfile.exe", "IEXPLORE.EXE")` is called. So there is indeed an explicit check for the exe name. But the question remains: Why?

Comment: This behavior seems to be a remnant of the first implementation of UAC. Read more: https://www.pandasecurity.com/mediacenter/malware/ms-deny-the-execution-of-ie7-if-the-executable-file-name-isnt-iexplore-exe/

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have found the reason. From the article, it seems to be a mechanism of IE's Protected Mode. Thanks for posting the related article..

Comment: @JackMiller I'm interested in this issue, and would like to use a debugger to take a deeper as well.
Could you clarify which debugger you used to be able to see that:


`Debugging revealed that _wcsicmp("myfile.exe", "IEXPLORE.EXE") is called.`

Comment: @JohnBlatz I am afraid I cannot say for sure which debugger, maybe OllyDbg. But please note that there is [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) now. [IE11 will end support June 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/internet-explorer-11-end-of-support), even though the [IEMode is not yet affected](https://aka.ms/IEModeFAQ) (ie. the WebBrowser component can still be used).